# Filter 2D numpy array if array element appears more than once

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to remove rows that share an element in a 2D array. For example:

```
array = [0 1]
        [2 3]
        [4 0]
        [0 4]

filtered_array = [2 3]
```

edit: column position does not matter

Comment: Share along the same column only or do we need to check other columns too?

Comment: Check both columns

Comment: So, you are working with two column arrays only?

Comment: Yes. The data is in the form of the example, just much longer.

Comment: What if the two elements in a row are the same, do we filter out that row based on that?

Comment: That should not happen. But it would not hurt, as it would avoid potential anomalies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def filter_rows(arr):
    # Detect matches along same columns for both cols
    samecol_mask1 = arr[:,None,0] == arr[:,0]
    samecol_mask2 = arr[:,None,1] == arr[:,1]
    samecol_mask = np.triu(samecol_mask1 | samecol_mask2,1)

    # Detect matches across the two cols
    diffcol_mask = arr[:,None,0] == arr[:,1]

    # Get the combined matching mask
    mask = samecol_mask | diffcol_mask

    # Get the indices of the mask which gives us the row IDs that have matches
    # across either same or different columns. Delete those rows for output. 
    dup_rowidx = np.unique(np.argwhere(mask))
    return np.delete(arr,dup_rowidx,axis=0)
```

**Sample runs to showcase various scenarios**

Case #1 : Multiple matches across same and different columns

```
In [313]: arr
Out[313]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 0],
       [0, 4]])

In [314]: filter_rows(arr)
Out[314]: array([[2, 3]])
```

Case #2 : Matches along same columns

```
In [319]: arr
Out[319]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10],
       [ 0,  4]])

In [320]: filter_rows(arr)
Out[320]: 
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

Case #3 : Matches along different columns

```
In [325]: arr
Out[325]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10],
       [ 7,  0]])

In [326]: filter_rows(arr)
Out[326]: 
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

Case #4 : Matches in the same row

```
In [331]: arr
Out[331]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 8, 10],
       [ 7,  0]])

In [332]: filter_rows(arr)
Out[332]: array([[ 8, 10]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative to the impressive solution of @Divakar. This approach is worse by all means (esp. efficiency), but maybe more understandable for non-numpy-gurus.

```
import numpy as np

def filter_(x):
    unique = np.unique(x) # 1
    unique_mapper = [np.where(x == z)[0] for z in unique] # 2
    filtered_unique_mapper = list(map(lambda x: x if len(x) > 1 else [], unique_mapper)) # 3
    all = np.concatenate(filtered_unique_mapper) # 4
    to_delete = np.unique(all) # 5
    return np.delete(x, all, axis=0)

# 1 get global unique values
# 2 for each unique value: get all rows with this value
#   -> multiple entries for one unique value: row's collide!
# 3 remove entries from above, if only <= 1 rows hold that unique value
# 4 collect all rows, which collided somehow
# 5 remove multiple entries from above
```